# D3 line is not displaying on chart when using timestamp as x-axis

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, frontend, visualization

Trying to display a simple line chart with a zoom function. The x-axis will have timestamp values, and the y-axis are values from 0-250.

Here is my code attempt:

```js
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return new Date(d.timestamp); }))
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 250])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
  .tickSize(-height)
  .tickPadding(10)
  .tickSubdivide(true)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
  .tickPadding(10)
  .tickSize(-width)
  .tickSubdivide(true)
    .orient("left");

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
//*********************************************************
// Generate our SVG object
//*********************************************************
var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .call(zoom)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "axis-label")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 10)
  .attr("x", -height/2)
  .text('spogtest');

svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

//*********************************************************
// Create D3 line object and draw data on our SVG object
//*********************************************************

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.Value); });

svg.selectAll('.line')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .attr('stroke', function(d,i){
    return colors[i%colors.length];
  })
    .attr("d", line);

//************************************************************
// Draw points on SVG object based on the data given
//************************************************************
var points = svg.selectAll('.dots')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "dots")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

points.selectAll('.dot')
  .data(function(d, index){
    let a = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        let point = d[i];
        a.push({'index': index, 'point': point});
    }
    return a;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('class','dot')
  .attr("r", 2.5)
  .attr('fill', function(d,i){
    return colors[d.index%colors.length];
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.point.timestamp) + "," + y(d.point.Value) + ")"; }
  );

//************************************************************
// Zoom specific updates
//************************************************************
function zoomed() {
  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
  svg.selectAll('path.line').attr('d', line);

  points.selectAll('circle').attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.point.timestamp) + "," + y(d.point.Value) + ")"; }
  );
}
```

From this, no error messages were displayed on chrome dev tools, but the line also does not show up at all. The axes and zoom functions seem to be working properly though. Here is the current chart:
[image: Current chart]

Also, it seems the code is detecting the 7 separate data points itself properly, because when I print the colors[d.index%colors.length] (on the drawing dots section), it displays the 7 colors in the colors variable, indicating the 7 lines that will be drawn from the given dataset. Hence, I am thinking it has something to do with the line drawing functionality itself.

I am quite new to d3.js, so any suggestions/tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you wish to zoom only the time scale or both?

Comment: Only time scale